# Laravel validation check if a value in database equals either one of two values

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I have a user database table that stores user roles. I need to validate if the user is either one of two roles in that table. Normally I could use `exists` but in this case, I need to check between two values.

How do I create a custom validation to do this? (I've an existing CustomValidator class)

E.g.

```
protected function validateUserRole($attribute, $value) {
    return (bool) ;
}
```

Columns in User role table:

```
id | user_id | role_id
```

Laravel rules:

```
$rules = array(
    'user_id' => ?
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: how do I put in multiple clauses? e.g. where role_id =1 or role_id=2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ModelName::where('id', '=', 1)->orWhere('id', '=', 2)->first();
```

Take a look at the example above; should help you out :)

Comment: Thanks! I used my User model in the custom validation and it worked